# How to setup bonobo git server to support git-lfs?

Tags: git, git-lfs, bonobo

[image: git command error]

I created a Bonobo git server on my LAN server. The base cmd "pull"or "push" has no problem. But when I tried to track large files and push it to server, it failed with the error messages below.

How should I setup the git server?

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin develop:develop
git: 'credential-wincerd' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
    credential-wincred

Pushing to http://IP/Git/GUI.git

Git LFS: (0 of 2 files) 0 B / 5.57 MB                                          
batch response: Repository or object not found: http://IP/Git/GUI.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it

error: failed to push some refs to 'http://IP/Git/GUI.git'
Completed with errors, see above.
```

Comment: Looks like there is a typo in your git setup - credential-wincerd instead of credential-wincred.

Comment: How should I fix this? I can’t found the credential-winced in config file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in one of your git config files (maybe the global config file) you have a typo.

Instead of typing

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

you probably typed

```
git config --global credential.helper wincerd
```

So just find the git config file that contains the string "wincerd" and fix the typo.